# Bootstrap 3 - multiple grid sytems in one site

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

For a project I'm woking on I want to fill the entire `.container` with 7 columns in my grid system. This I can achieve by manipulating the correct Less variable (`@grid-columns`) before compiling a bootstrap.css file at http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system.

But, what if I at another instance of the same site want to go back to the normal 12 column grid system?

If I was to create another bootstrap.css, leaving the `@grid-columns` at 12, I still couldn't load it to a browser since it would conflict with the previously created bootstrap.css since similar class references would be used in both (e.g. `.col-md-7`) css files.

Can't wrap my head around this problem, but there must be a way, right?!? Or, maybe I'm just missing something.

Answer (score 2):

Well you could go with 84 columns. And use it so that if you need 7 columns then one column width would be 12 bootstrap columns. `12 12 12 12 12 12 12 = 84`

And if you need 12 columns then one column width would be 7 bootstrap columns.
`7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 = 84`

This should work although it might need a lot of calculations at first.

Just a basic math solution if nothing else works.

---

Another solution would be to fork the SASS or LESS version of bootstrap and generate your own version of bootstrap. For example you add classes similar to `col-7-xs-...`. I just checked the SASS version. And in the `_grid-framework.scss` file there are mixinis you could probably change and use so that you should easily be able to add your own grid classes.

I don't see why that shouldn't work.

Comment: Hm... Not bad suggestions. I think I'll have to especially venture into the second one and see if I can make anything of that!

Comment: That's 4096 lines of unpacked CSS just for the grid, not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

First you should ask yourself whether a couple instances of 7 columns is worth requiring another grid system. Let's look this page http://getbootstrap.com/components/ they have 8 "columns" for the icons, but they don't use the grid system, they write appropriate custom CSS to do the job with an unordered list.

**Here's an idea:**

### https://jsbin.com/pofofe/1/

https://jsbin.com/pofofe/1/edit?html,css,output

**HTML (the comments are to prevent the extra space from inline-block)**

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row seven-col">
    
    <div>1</div><!-- do not remove 
    --><div>2</div><!-- do not remove 
    --><div>3</div><!-- do not remove 
    --><div>4</div><!-- do not remove 
    --><div>5</div><!-- do not remove 
    --><div>6</div><!-- do not remove 
    --><div>7</div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.row.seven-col {
    text-align: center
}
.row.seven-col > div {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    min-height: 30px;
}
@media (min-width:480px) { 
    .row.seven-col > div {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50%;
    }
}
@media (min-width:600px) { 
    .row.seven-col > div {
        width: 25%
    }
}
@media (min-width:992px) { 
    .row.seven-col > div {
        width: 14.285%
    }
}
```

As you can see this will work smoothly and it has significantly fewer lines of CSS than another copy of the grid system.

**IMPORTANT:**

.img-responsive does not work inside inline-block or tables or display:table etc., use:

```
.row.seven-col img {width:100%;height:auto;}
```